# testng running on linux maven command line

Tags: java, linux, maven, automated-tests, testng

How to run `testng.xml` file from maven commands in linux command line?

I am new to automation. I have created a maven project(java) using Interlij Idea for testing a web page. I can run test groups in testng.xml using Idea.

What I need now is running those test groups from the linux command line.(running the testng xml file)

Comment: How do you test your webpage via Selenium ?

Comment: Just assertions.Verifying whether elements are present.That stuff is ok.I mean I can manage that part for now.
thanks khmarbaise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to [download maven on linux](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/installation-sect-maven-install.html) and then AFAIK the commands shouldn't be any different so you can use the [surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) in your pom and specify the suiteXmlFile param to mvn test command, something like 
`mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=/src/test/resources/yourxml.xml`

Hope it helps..

Comment: It is working for me,Now I can run test suite using command line.

But I have defined test groups for test cases.Still I can not run according to those test groups from the command line.
Ex- When I need to run only a particular test group, how can I call that from command line?

Thanks a lot niharika_neo

Comment: I guess there should be a tick icon right below the up-down vote button beside the answer where the vote count is...